# Can anybody explain this paragraph for me, please?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean "Because millions of baby boomers are the main buyers of these old cars, and now they have financial problems leading to there will be fewer buyers for these ones"? OR "Because millions of baby boomers WERE the main buyers of these old cars, and now they have financial problems leading to most of them want to sell these ones, making the price go down"?

> But there are headwinds to the amount these cars fetch at auction.
>   Millions of baby boomers, the natural buyers for many of these
>   nostalgic throwbacks, are now bracing for retirement and face an
>   uncertain health insurance landscape as the current administration
>   revamps the existing health care law.

SOURCE: http://www.marketwatch.com/story/this-car-from-your-childhood-has-increased-in-value-by-58000-2017-03-22

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence is straightforward. It asserts that it's hard to get high prices for "these cars". The reason is given in the second sentence.

The second sentence has an [appositive](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/appositive.htm) that equates the following:

- baby boomers; and
- the natural buyers for many of these nostalgic throwbacks.

The second sentence asserts that millions of these people are facing retirement etc.

Putting it together, the paragraph suggests that because of the situation facing many of the natural buyers of these cars, it will be difficult to get high prices when selling the cars at auction.